# Mongoid relations with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, devise, mongoid

I have some rails application with MongoDB, Mongoid mapper and devise. Аuthorized user can create, edit, delete post(scaffold) and comment this posts. I take for comment model example of Ryan Bates screencasts, 238 episode "Mongoid".

comment.rb

```
class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  field :content
  embedded_in :post, :inverse_of => :comments
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post
      include Mongoid::Document
      field :name
      field :content
      validates_presence_of :name
      embeds_many :comments
    end
```

user.rb

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  field :username

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_many :comments
  references_many :post

end
```

But when I try to register new user, in registration form push "Sign up", I see this error

```
Mongoid::Errors::MixedRelations in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

Referencing a(n) Comment document from the User document via a relational association is not allowed since the Comment is embedded.
```

I start this apllication with Mysql db, and then decided to move into mongo.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your question needs a better title -- in the form of a question. As it is it's vague.

Comment: Why not roll your own auth? It's pretty simple in rails 3.1. Watch this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1 If you absolutely need devise I can take a look, but chances are that just doing it yourself will be better/simpler.

Comment: @Tyler: Devise is pretty comprehensive. It's well tested and has been around a while. You'd have to make a pretty strong argument for rolling your own, considering the time involved.

Comment: jcollum, fair haha, but if he's not using any of the advanced features, he'd be done implementing it by now.

Comment: Thanks Tyler for recommendation. I will try to understand devise and decide I need that(devise) or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Comment is embedded in Post you should have User referencing Post. Try removing `has_many :comments` in User.

Comment: I try that. It works, but if I need to get all user comments?

Comment: The you should not be embedding the users in the posts. You should references it instead. http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/v3/relations.html#has_many